# How to convert/change date format from MM/DD/YYYY to Month Date, Year?

Tags: javascript, date, calendar, blogs, converters

I'm trying to convert/change my blog date from MM/DD/YYYY to Month Date, Year. For example, this date 11/12/2018 convert to November 12, 2018. Is there a way to do this correctly?

I've tried a code that suppose to work. However, the code converted/changed every blog posts' date to recent published posts' (date).

I tried this code:

```
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var data = $('.date-text').text();
var arr = data.split('/');
$(".date-text").html(months[parseInt(arr[0]) - 1] + " " + arr[1] + ", " + arr[2]);
```

and code converted all dates to recent published posts' date, which is now displayed as November 12, 2018 11.

Working editor: https://jsfiddle.net/s1b2fenk/

Website's image after date changed:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that in jQuery:

```
$(".date-text").html(...);
```

changes the HTML of all elements selected by *.date-text* to the same value, so they all end up showing the same date.

You can use jQuery's *.each* method something like:

```js
$(".date-text").each(function (){
  var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April",
                "May", "June", "July", "August",
                "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  var arr = this.textContent.split('/');
  this.textContent = months[parseInt(arr[0]) - 1] + " " + arr[1] + ", " + arr[2];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="date-text">11/12/2018</div>
<div class="date-text">10/1/2018</div>
```

You might find it simpler to use POJS:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.querySelectorAll('.date-text').forEach(el => el.textContent = formatDateString(el.textContent))
}, false);

function formatDateString(s) {
  var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  var arr = s.split('/');
  return months[arr[0] - 1] + " " + arr[1] + ", " + arr[2];
}
```

```html
<div class="date-text">11/12/2018</div>
<div class="date-text">10/1/2018</div>
```

Comment: Code works amazingly! Thank you for your kind work :)

Answer (score 0):

it's because there are many div's with same class name, which when `$('.class-name').html()` you do, it'll change all the div's with the same class name. you can try giving different classes or change the contents of json when you get the data from server.

Answer (score 0):

> This is by using pure javascript and jQuery. This code does not
>   require any other library except jquery.

```
<div class="date-text-1">
11/12/2018
</div>

<div class="date-text-2">
10/1/2018
</div>
<div class="Converted-1">

</div>
<div class="Converted-2">

</div>
```

> This is javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

var data1 = $('.date-text-1').text();
var converteddate1=new Date(data1);
var formatedDate1=months[converteddate1.getMonth()]+' '+converteddate1.getDate()+','+converteddate1.getFullYear();
$('.Converted-1').text(formatedDate1);

var data2 = $('.date-text-2').text();
var converteddate2=new Date(data2);
var formatedDate2=months[converteddate2.getMonth()]+' '+converteddate2.getDate()+','+converteddate2.getFullYear();
$('.Converted-2').text(formatedDate2);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you know about moment.js or date-fns ? This will do it for you.

Anyway your problem come certainly from the way "data" is computed. (and it's not explained in your code extract). You may console.log(data, arr) to check their value.

Comment: This should be a comment, it's not an answer.